# How to include PHP code in welcome email?

Tags: 7, emails

I need PHP (for some logic) inside the welcome email, the welcome email structure is defined in `admin/config/people/accounts` (in the text box)

How can I place PHP code there? I tried to put some PHP but I only get a blank email. Or if I can`t execute PHP code inside the email box what module can I use to do this?

Comment: Have you check PHP mailer ?

Comment: _Please_ don't use the php module, it's a huge security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Updated :

Use [PHP mailer](https://www.drupal.org/node/930090) module to send the email in the format of php

Comment: It`s not compatible with Drupal 7.x

Comment: I have updated the answer link. Click on PHP mailer. You can use development module.

Comment: Is your issue is solved @VladimirSabo

Comment: No, unfortunately that is not the right solution for me, I need to send the mail with the current system and not with a custom module.